# How to create a project from maven in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've installed the m2e plugin in Eclipse. I'm trying to download the source and dependencies of [MG4J](http://mg4j.dsi.unimi.it/) and use it in my project. In the upper-right corner there's a Maven link. However, I don't know what to do with it! I downloaded the source and opened a file and found the SCM location. I entered it in the "Checkout Maven Projects from SCM" project type, but when I click finish, nothing happened. How can I achieve this?

### Update:

I'm new to the world of Java. What I'm trying to do is this: I wanted to use MG4J in my project. I think I might have to change its code. First I downloaded the source and dependencies archives and extracted them, added .jar files to the build path and everything compiled. But it failed to run on some occasions. I contacted the MG4J people. They said that I have to use Maven to resolve dependencies. Now, here I am with all the archives and after 1 day, I still can't run a simple program.

In short I want to do this:

project 1: MG4J (automatically resolves dependencies, etc)

project 2: MyProject (relies on MG4J)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MG4J uses Ant with Ivy (not Maven) as a build tool and dependency manager. So, if you want to be able to modify the source and build it you are going to have to use the same tools.

1. Install Apache Ant, make a note of the installation directory (ANT_HOME)
2. Download an [Apache Ivy binary distribution](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi)
3. Unpack the Apache Ivy binary distribution to a folder, then copy ivy-2.x.x.jar to ANT_HOME/lib
4. Download [the source for MG4J](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22it.unimi.di%22). It comes as a JAR which you need to extract to a folder (MG4J_SRC).
5. In the MG4J_SRC folder execute the command `ant ivy-setupjars jar`. If the build is successful, it will create a binary distribution for MG4J, as a JAR called mg4j-x.x.jar.

So, now you have a locally built version of the library, but you still can't use it (easily) in Maven. To make it accessible to your Mavenised project, you should install the library into your local Maven repo.

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile={MG4J_SRC}/mg4j-x.x.jar
                          -DgroupId=your.groupId
                          -DartifactId=your.artifactId
                          -Dversion=your.version
                          -Dpackaging=jar
                          -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

*Replace the your.groupId, your.artifactId, your.version and localRepositoryPath variables with values that make sense for your environment*

You can then add a dependency to the other project's POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>your-artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>your.version</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, as a final step, you want to make working with the MG4J source possible (and easy) from within Eclipse. In your IDE, open `File->New->Project` and select 'Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile' (type Ant in your Filter to narrow down the list).

[image: New Ant Project]

Click through the wizard and Finish. Now you have an Ant-based project in Eclipse, where you can easily modify the source and execute builds. As a last step, you can change the `deploy` target in the MG4J build.xml file to install the MG4J into your local repository (as opposed to pushing it to Maven Central).

Comment: This way he can add the dependency, but I think he is trying to load the source code of this project

Comment: To me it sounds like he just wants to use MG4J in his project, but is unsure of how to get it pulled down via Maven.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. Please read it. I tried these, but still failed. What should I do?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - ok, I get what you are trying to do now. See my (radically) updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed it through and got the following error when I ran `ant ivy-setupjars jar`: Could not launch ln: java.io.IOException: cannot run program "ln": CreateProcess error=2...

Comment: Are you running on Windows? You may need to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) if so.

Comment: @Perception Thanks. After installing cygwin, the build was successful. Now it doesn't recognize `mvn`. My question is, can I skip using the maven and skip to the last part where I create the project from ant file? I did that and added a reference to the created project. It was successful. However, I get the same error I got before all this!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24927/discussion-between-perception-and-alireza-noori)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the MG4j dependency in your project pom file

```
<dependencies>
  [...]
  <dependency>
    <groupId>it.unimi.di</groupId>
    <artifactId>mg4j</artifactId>
    <version>5.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your question, this is the way to use MG4J in your project, if you want to download source, modify it and use modified version in your project you need several step. 1st one is to dowload source and import in eclipse as a maven project, then use the project as a maven module on which your own project will depends (maven multimodule)

Comment: Please read the update. I tried opening the .xml file with notepad and adding this to it, it failed!

Answer (score 0):

Try download the source code into your workspace directory, then in eclipse try Import->Maven->"Existing Maven Project" and point to source code directory of the project. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This created the project successfully. But when I added a reference to this project, the classes were not recognized!

Answer (score 0):

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` will create the shims that eclipse needs, then create the project and you should be golden.

Comment: Where should I type this into?